How to convert std::filesystem::file_time_type to FILETIME form in c++17?
How to convert std::filesystem::file_time_type to FILETIME in C++17?
I'm expecting to get code example/snippet converting a variable of std::filesystem::file_time_type to a structure of type FILETIME in C++17/C++11.

"I'm expecting to get code example/snippet converting a variable of std::filesystem::file_time_type to a structure of a type FILETIME in c++17/c++11" - So you are basically expecting StackOverflow to be a free code writing service. That's not how it works.

#include <Windows.h>

#include <chrono>
#include <filesystem>

FILETIME
file_clock_to_FILETIME(std::filesystem::file_time_type tp)
{
    const uint64_t rawCount = tp.time_since_epoch().count();
    FILETIME result;
    result.dwLowDateTime = static_cast<DWORD>(rawCount);
    result.dwHighDateTime = static_cast<DWORD>(rawCount >> 32);
    return result;
}

Demo.
This works because file_time_type and FILETIME share the same epoch and precision.  So one just has to extract the 64 bit integral type and stuff it into the FILETIME data structure.

Alt. assign the count() to the QuadPart of a ULARGE_INTEGER and then assign its HighPart to dwHighDateTime and its LowPart to dwLowDateTime. example

Do you think Microsoft had some undue influence on the standards committee to get them to choose the same format they were already using?

If you're speaking of the epoch and precision of filesystem::file_time_type, no, they didn't.  This epoch and precision is unspecified by the standard.  Microsoft has the freedom to choose 1601-01-01 and 100ns.  And gcc has the freedom to choose 2174-01-01 and 1ns.  The committee granted this freedom so that platforms could operate at their peak efficiency, and offer their customers the best solution.  OTOH, the system_clock epoch is now specified to be 1970-01-01.  The committee was able to standardize existing practice for this clock.  And clients benefit from this common epoch.
